# Invalid value specified for function parameter. Function Name: DatePart Parameter Name: Date Parameter

Tags: ampscript

I have a landing page that allows you to insert the contact data modifier. For the modification on I must first retrieve the contact information dynamically. That I want to launch the page I am displayed an error message that relates to the date:

> Invalid value specified for the function parameter. Function Name: DatePart Parameter Name: Date Parameter

This is my code AMPScript:

```
/* SET @date = field(@date,"BIRTHDATE")*/ 
SET @year = DatePart(@date,"Y")
SET @month = DatePart(@date,"M")
SET @day = DatePart(@date,"D")    
IF 
    EMPTY(@date) AND ISNULL(@date) THEN SET @Date=""    
ELSE
    SET @Date=CONCAT(@day,"/",@month,"/",@year)                 
ENDIF
```

Comment: Probably need more context to get to the bottom of this - however, in that code snippet you have posted you have commented out the part that sets the date - a null date will bring back an invalid parameter from the DatePart function if I remember correctly.

Comment: thank you for your update.
to understand better, I want to get the birthday of the contact in the birthday field, so with this code, I want to take the value of the birthday from the Salesforce Marketing Cloud and posted in the field